# X13ARIMA & statsmodels: X13NotFoundError: x12a and x13as not found on path

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am on Window OS. I downloaded the Windows version of X13 software from https://www.census.gov/data/software/x13as.X-13ARIMA-SEATS.html#list-tab-635278563.

I would like to use it with my Python code as below.
But I get error:
**X13NotFoundError: x12a and x13as not found on path. Give the path, put them on PATH, or set the X12PATH or X13PATH environmental variable.**

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

s = pd.Series(
    {Timestamp('2013-03-01 00:00:00'): 838.2,
 Timestamp('2013-04-01 00:00:00'): 865.17,
 Timestamp('2013-05-01 00:00:00'): 763.0})
     
     
import os
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\user-name\Downloads\x13as_ascii-v1-1-b59\x13as')

import statsmodels.api as sm
sm.tsa.x13_arima_analysis(s)
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying the `x12path` parameter when calling `x13_arima_analysis`? (see [docs](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.x13.x13_arima_analysis.html)).

Comment: @AlexK: Thanks for the reply. 
I tried sm.tsa.x13_arima_analysis(s, x12path='C:\Users\user-name\Downloads\x13as_ascii-v1-1-b59\x13as'), but I got the same error

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem by:

1. Step 1: changing to `x13as_ascii.exe` to `x13as.exe`
2. Step 2:

   import os
   os.chdir(r'C:\Users\user-name\Downloads\x13as_ascii-v1-1-b59\x13as')